# Apache Virtual host not recognized

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk

I've been using one server, then I reinstalled everything on another server, and the mod_jk stopped working. Here is the situation:

- apache 2.0 sitting "in front"
- mod_jk used to connect to the apache to tomcat
- tomcat 6.0.26 used to server the actual requests

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mogilowski.net/?p=121). The result is:

- accessing `http://mysite.com` opens the index.html in `/var/www/`
- accessing `http://mysite.com:8080/` works OK
- the logs at `/var/logs/apache2` show everything is OK:

> [Mon Mar 29 22:01:53.310 2010] [28349:3075389184] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (2830): mod_jk/1.2.26 initialized
>
> [Mon Mar 29 22:01:53 2010] [warn] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
>   [Mon Mar 29 22:01:53 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.26 configured -- resuming normal operations

I compared the `server.xml`, `jk.conf`, `sites-enabled/mysite` from the new server to those from the old one and they are identical.

The domain name is the same (I updated the DNS record today, and it has refreshed successfully)

So the question is, what can go wrong? Is there another place where problems would be logged, if such occur?

Update What I can be almost certain of is that the virtual host is not recognized. It is always forwarded to the default virtual host. So, how to make sure the virtual host is recognized and working?

Relevant parts of apache2.conf:

```
# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Comment: Post your complete Apache httpd configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your vhosts setup:

```
    . /etc/apache2/envvars; apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

This might give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of tomcat ?
I only get this problem with version 7 (which is currently beta !) Try tomcat 6.